# Does abandoning the survivors have any lasting affect on the plot?

Tags: the-sinking-city

In the Lost At Sea quest, the player is given the choice to abandon the survivors or save the survivors. However, it doesn't mention what affects this will have on the game other than "the disease may spread".

The only relevant information I can find on the topic is...

> [When you talk to Throgmorton, you have to choose two options. Either way that your expeditions needs help or say that the expedition members have died. If you choose for them to be saved, you will risk the madness to spread even further.](https://www.gameshedge.com/the-sinking-city-lost-at-sea-walkthrough/)

...but that doesn't really give much actual information on the affects of the decision.

So, is there any affects on the overall plot of the game whether you save the survivors or not?